# Typescript unable to detect non-null type

Tags: typescript

This is the error I'm getting in VS Code:

[image]

I tried a bunch of different things, lastly the most explicit `selectedDate !== null`, so as to say, hey, it's definitely not null. What am I missing here?

actual code:

```
selectedDate !== null ? selectedDate.getTime() === day.getTime() : false
```

var is instantiated as such, from beginning of `render()` method like so:

`const { selectedDate } = this.state`

and state is defined in the class like so:

```
state = {
  selectedDate: null
}
```

Since it is null here, and loaded as a const, i guess typescript assumes it can only ever be null. even if it is not equal to null.

Comment: What you're missing is posting some actual code in the question that shows the problem. A screenshot that doesn't even show the complete line in question really isn't much use. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Duncan I'll update with non-screenshot code.. included the screenshot to show the actual error from typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you declared `selectedDate` with the type `null`? The tooltip is trying to give you a hint about where it inferred the type, and the snippet it shows says `const selectedDate: null`. Using a `null` check as a type guard only works if the type is a union of `null` and another type.

Note that a variable declared with `const` cannot be reassigned, and AFAIK the type of a variable will not change on reassignment.

Answer (score 1):

Can you `selectedDate` variable can be `null`?
If so that message actually helps you

If not, **but use with care**, and only if you're sure that the variable can never be null use the *bang* attribute like so:

`selectedDate!.getTime ()`

notice the `!` after `selectedDate`

But as @Duncan tolds you in the comment, next time to have mode accurates answer, provides example of codes instead of screens ;)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
state = {
  selectedDate: undefined
} as {
  selectedDate?: Date
}
```